# What is the prototype and __proto__ of a subclass

Tags: javascript

In the following `class` and inherited class declarations:

```js
class Polygon {};
class Triangle extends Polygon {};
console.log(
    Polygon.prototype, Polygon.__proto__, 
    Triangle.prototype, Triangle.__proto__
);
```

What is the `prototype` and `__proto__` of a top-level class? And then of a subclass? It seems the only sort of identity I can figure out is that `Triangle.__proto__ === Polygon`.

Comment: The prototype of the top-level class is the `Object` constructor function. That's the native code that gets logged.

Comment: @Barmar I see, so what then would be the equality? `Polygon.prototype === Object...` ?

Comment: @Barmar It seems this works, two removed -- ```class Polygon {};
class Triangle extends Polygon {};
console.log(Polygon.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype);```, but then what is just `Polygon.__proto__` equal to?

Comment: @Barmar It's `Function.prototype`. Only a `class extends Object` actually inherits from `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

### `prototype`

A class's prototype object is instance values to pass on to a new instance of the class.

### `__proto__`

From what I can see, this looks like it's always the parent class.